# Shortest path around a cone

Tags: geometry

If you build a shortest distance track for a siteseeing train around the mountain, in which the track starts at point A and ends up at point B, the track will first go uphill, but then it will go downhill.

How can one prove, using only geometry that this path goes  up hill, then downhill?

Comment: [This (click here)](https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2018/03/28/can-you-solve-a-hard-korean-test-question-cone-shaped-mountain-puzzle/) might be relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Unfold the lateral surface of the cone to get a circular sector: the shortest path is then a straight line from $A$ to $B$. The point on $AB$ which is the nearest to the vertex is also the highest point on the mountain path. This point can be interior to segment $AB$, depending on the position of $A$ and $B$.

[image]

Comment: For fun, check out the properties of the geodesic when the angle between the lateral surface and the axis is less than 30°.